# Postgresql dump permission denied

Tags: postgresql

I get this error while trying to dump database, i entered

```
linuxuser $ sudo su postgres
linuxuser $ [sudo] password for linuxuser:...
$ pg_dump -h localhost mydb >tempfile
$ sh: cannot create tempfile: Permission denied
```

What the problem? i've just installed fresh postgresql.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Write into directory where postgres user has write access. For instance `/tmp`.

```
$ pg_dump -h localhost mydb >/tmp/tempfile
```

In your attempt postgres user tries to create a file in some random directory belonging to the other user.

Answer (score 10):

backup and restore can be done by any unpriviledged user that knows the postgres superuser password by changing permissions on the working directory:

```
% mkdir backup

% chmod 0777 backup

% su postgres

[enter password]

$ cd backup

$ pg_dump mydb >tempfile

$ exit
```

"tempfile" will be owned by postgres and same group as the user

Answer (score 7):

sudo su postgres doesn't change the current directory so you're still in linuxuser's home directory and postgres has no permission to write into it.
Change to a different directory

Answer (score 2):

## `postgres` User

As the other correct answers said, the folder in which you are trying save the backup does not have permissions assigned to the `postgres` user (operating system user account). The `postgres` user is the one running the backup utility. This user account was created during the Postgres installation process. You may have used a different name, but the default is `postgres`.

## Folder With Permissions

The solution is to **either find or create a folder** where the `postgres` user has read-write permissions.

## Mac OS X

In Mac OS X (Mountain Lion), I am able to create such a folder in the Finder.

1. In the Finder, create a new folder. Select it.
   In this example, I created a folder named `postgres_backups`.
2. Choose `File` > `Get Info`.
3. Open the disclosure triangle for the `Sharing & Permissions` section.
4. Click the Plus button to add another item to the list of users.
   A list of users appears in a "sheet" dialog.
5. Select the `postgres` user from the list.
6. In the `Privilege` column, for the new `postgres` row, change the popup menu to `Read & Write`.
7. Close the `Get Info` window. Done.

Now you can direct your Postgres backup files to that folder.

[image: screen shot of a "Get Info" window in the Finder]

By the way, I use the pgAdmin app to do backups and restores. Control+click on the desired database and choose `Backups…`. The pgAdmin app was probably bundled with your Postgres installation.

Answer (score 2):

first thing you have to do is do not switch to user postgres. The use this command for backup:

```
pg_dump -U username -h localhost dbname > /db.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

for me I had to write a full filename like dump.sql at the end, like ewhite5.

Answer (score -3):

I wrestled with this "Permission Denied" issue while trying to backup my PSQL database on an Ubuntu machine for a long time, and tried user access rights, superuser status, folder properties--lots of stuff. Finally, something worked that was ridiculously simple. In the command:

```
pg_dump -U username -O dbname > 'filename.sql'
```

Make sure you have quotes (single or double quotes seem to work) around the filename which follows the greater than (">") sign. The examples above do not have quotes around the filename. Once I tried that, I no longer received Permission Denied errors.