# How to run pg_dump/pg_dumpall command on Linux?

Tags: linux, postgresql, pg-dump, pg-dumpall

Hello everyone i am try to create backup in postgres through dump. when i run the command through command line it wants password when i give the password it will give some error

```
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "nsdgpkidb" failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "root"
```

if any one have some valuable time please help me thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Such kind of questions are better to ask on [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com).
You have to provide pg_dump with the valid postgresql account via command line parameter:

```
pg_dump -U postgres nsdgpkidb > file.sql
```

By default it assumes the current local user account (root). Another way is to [change the current user](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8835835/55209) and issue the command.

Comment: where will the dump file get saved?

Comment: @user1735921 `> file.sql` means file.sql in the current directory, or you can use full or relative path, like `> /path/to/file/file.sql`

Comment: @ArtemKoshelev server fault or [DBA](http://dba.stackexchange.com/)? ;)

Comment: @user1735921 you can define the path absolute:  `pg_dump -U postgres name_of_BD > '/dir_to_backup/Class_international.sql'`